# Including js/css scripts in Shiny app

Tags: javascript, css, r, tags, shiny

I am building a Shiny application, but as it should get arguments for data for building plots, I decided to save my app as a function (using this tutorial: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/function.html ).

Everything is working besides javascript and stylesheets that I would like to include (it was working earlier when I had standard structure: ui.R, server.R and included js/css files were in 'www' folder).

I tried to:
- adding the files in the 'www' folder as before (*[script.R, www folder: [style.css, script.js]]*)
- adding the files in separate folder, but in the same directory as the script launching the Shiny app (*[script.R, scripts folder: [style.css, script.js]]*)
- adding the files in the same directory as my script launching the Shiny app (*[script.R, style.css, script.js]*)

For including files I use code like:
    tags$head(tags$script(src="graph.js"))

Do you have any suggestions how to include scripts when you save your Shinny application as a function?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who may be having the same issue, I finally came up with the solution :-) There are 'include' functions in Shiny that let you specify a file with the absolute/relative path. Here is the reference: http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/include.html

And this is my example code:

```
app <- function(data)
{
 shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
   fluidRow(
    # I created a 'www' folder that was included
    # in the package that is launching Shiny app
    tags$head(includeScript(system.file('www', 'script.js', package = 'myPackage'))),
    tags$head(includeCSS(system.file('www', 'style.css', package = 'myPackage'))),
    # some UI stuff
   )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
   # some server stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is now different. `system.file` is not required for `includeScript`

So: 
    `tags$head(includeScript(system.file('www', 'script.js', package = 
    'myPackage')))`

Will be:

`tags$head(includeScript('www/script.js', 'type' = 'text/javascript', 'data-unique-tag' = 'unique'))`

Comment: This approach without the system.file does not seem to work for me. I simply get an error that the file path is not found. Looking at `?htmltools::includeScript` it also does not mention anything that it takes that packages into account. 

So I am not sure how you would get around the fact of using `system.file(..., package = 'myPackage')`